# Pulling in files from different folder

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a webpage that is located in a different folder than the root folder. I'm trying to pull in the newsletter.css file, the header.php file, and the `services.jpg` file. The working page is located at Root/newsletters/newsletter-2020-01.php. The header.php file is located in the Root folder, the newsletter.css is located at `Root/styles/newsletter.css` and lastly, the services.jpg is located at `Root/images/services.jpg`. The working file (Root/newsletters/newsletter-2020-01.php) isn't pulling in any of the other files. I've looked for the answer on Stackoverflow and everything is saying to use ../file.ext but this isn't working. Any advice?

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/newsletter.css">
    </head>
    <?php include("../header.php");?>
    <div class="background_image" style="background-image:url(../images/services.jpg)"></div>
```

Comment: if `Root` is the document root and doesn't appear in the url just use `root relative` paths - ie: `/images/services.jpg` or `/styles/newsletter.css`

Answer (score 0):

For server level files (pulling in PHP files etc. that are done on the server, not the browser).

Use: **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']**, it's a sure thing.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] it gives you the full path of your server to the root where your HTML etc. files are stored.  From there you use the path to the exact file you want.

To see it in action: `<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>`
It will make more sense.

Ex. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/directory/myfile.php'`

As for browser level files (files accessed by the browser, .css, .js)
Use an **absolute path** from the root, again, a sure thing.

Ex. `<script language="javascript" src="/directory/scripts/myjavascript.js"></script>`

Why?

Relative paths can be broken if the file moves around.  It may be relative to FileA, but FileB may be in a different location, or FileA may move, or be included in another file.

Absolute paths are a sure thing!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a physical directory structure ( on Windows ) such as:

```
C:\wwwroot\htdocs\example
                    |_css
                    |_scripts
                    |_images
                        |_galleries
                        |_icons
                        |_banners
                    |_gallery
```

In the above typically `example` would be set as the document root and a call to `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` would yield `c:/wwwroot/htdocs/example` etc
An `Absolute` or `Root Relative` path for css, images, scripts etc would begin with a leading slash. So, to access css files you might do:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/theme.css' />
```

or for an images

```
<img src='/images/banners/logo.png' />
```

If you start the path with `../` you are instructing the browser to fetch the resource beginning 1 folder higher ( than the current directory ) and then follow the given path. Similarly if you use `../../` that means "go up 2 levels" and begin searching from that point. There is a place for this syntax but it can be confusing and very easy to get wrong.

If you begin the path for a resource with no leading slash ( such as `images/example.png` ) you are instructing the browser to fetch the resource from the same level OR a sub-folder. In the given example here `images/example.png` suggests the image is within a sub-folder of the given path so if you are accessing the page at `https://localhost/gallery/beach/index.php` it would mean that there needs to be a folder structure `C:\wwwroot\htdocs\example\gallery\beach\images` for that to work ( unless using advanced trickery with the server config )

When it comes to including additional PHP scripts you can do so a little differently. It is not essential and in most cases it can be preferable to have the files you wish to include outside of the document root. Using the same base structure from above and having a directory for commonly included files outside of `document root` would mean that using a browser you could not directly open files in the `includes` directory - so for example: `https://localhost/includes/secrets.php` would fail but that file could easily be included from within PHP.

To include other PHP files you can tweak the `includes_path` variable using `set_include_path()` and thus allow PHP to include files from outwith the site root.

```
c:\wwwroot\htdocs\includes
```

You could ensure that all PHP scripts ( such as db connections and other class files ) are easily included by setting the `includes_path`:

```
set_include_path( 'c:\wwwroot\htdocs\includes' );
```

and then, to include a file from that directory:

```
require 'db.php';
```

You can set this to use the full path instead or you can use the `../../` style syntax also.