# Display bootstrap card on top right of the screen

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How can I move my Bootstrap card to the top-right of the screen?

This is my current html code (a snippet of it):

```
<div class="card-text" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{c.Name}} {{c.Surname}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ c.role }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have looked through the documentation of bootstrap and tried almost everything. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move it by putting it in a wrapper. If you don't want to add it to a CSS you can just place it within style tags in the HTML head.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
       <head>
          <!-- Required meta tags -->
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <style>
             #wrapper {
             position: absolute;
             top: 0;
             right: 0;
             }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div id='wrapper'>
             <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class='card-text' style='max-width: 18rem;'>
                   <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                   <div class='card-body'>
                      <h5 class='card-title'>{{c.Name}} {{c.Surname}}</h5>
                      <p class='card-text'>{{ c.role }}</p>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go...

You have to **wrap your content with a wrapper** and add this to your CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div id='wrapper'>
    <div class='card-text' style='max-width: 18rem;'>
      <div class='card-body'>
        <h5 class='card-title'>{{c.Name}} {{c.Surname}}</h5>
        <p class='card-text'>{{ c.role }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have multiple css files, where do i need to add it?

Comment: Just add this to the one of your existing CSS files. It doesn't matter which one, as long as you add this CSS file to your HTML.

Comment: okay, so suppose I have a css file called "example.css" located in static/admin/css/example.css  Do I have to add; <link rel="stylesheet" href= "static.admin/css/example.css"> ? Because that didn't work :s

Comment: Where is your HTML located? In the same folder as "example.css"? Be careful, change `href= "static.admin/css/example.css"` to `href= "static/admin/css/example.css"`. You should have a slash, not a dot here.

Comment: No, my html is located on app/templates/example.html and my example css at the root directory under static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.css

Comment: My solution works for sure. The problem is in your path (i.e., `href`). Please tell me exactly your folder structure. Edit your question and add folder structure like  @Professor Abronsius did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578735/pulling-in-files-from-different-folder?rq=1

Comment: when I have the file example.css with the wrapper in it, in exactly my same directory as my html file, using <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css"> doesn't work...